Why have my stair lights stopped working?
I have LED bulbs underneath my front stairs to light up at night. They were set up and were functioning great when I moved in, but have recently stopped working. All of them. I assume there is a power source issue but when I investigated I found that although all of the lights are wired together, that they aren't connected to any power source. The wires just run between the lights themselves. There is no power unit, battery pack or anything and they don't appear to be solar-powered at all. So I'm very confused as to how they were even getting power and why they appear to have stopped now. Any help is appreciated.
underside wiring
close up of light

Picture will help.  Have seen solar panels for some lights be about 1 or 2 square inches.  There needs be a power source(maybe be missing now), so recheck the wires/lights.  Maybe a connector at one end that is missing wires now.

Thanks, @crip659. I've attached a close up of one of the lights and also show that each light is wired to each other, but again I can't find any wires or power units anywhere that would even run to a power source. I'm hoping that the pics may help and someone can identify if there is a small solar panel or battery somewhere. But even so, the fact that they all stopped working at once makes me certain I'm missing something.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/19I2j-Ivllm7tvQ-w4XBhsmfpe3i6EX3B/view?usp=drive_link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ik22CQO9pzHzbL4QFJPuFJ4HwHd7u1J4/view?usp=drive_link

Need to make the pictures open to public.  Have them protected right now.  Or use the edit button with the mountain/sun icon to post here.

Thanks. They should be open and available now.

@WesCronkite please add the pictures to the question ... they do not belong in comments ... attach directly into question, not in a link

Pictures are still inaccessible.

how did you turn them on before? ... maybe someone stole the power supply

follow that wire see where else it goes

Upload your images to an image host, not a file sharing service.

Upload your images into this question text, so the images appear right here without further navigation required from the reader. Use crip659's instructions earlier in comments.
